# Фильтрация объектов по подобъектам в Django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

Есть две модели:

```
class Object(models.Model):
   // ..

class Subobject(models.Model):
   STATUS_CHOICES = (
     ('ST1', 'Статус 1'),
     ('ST2', 'Статус 2'),
     ('ST3', 'Статус 3')
   )
   status = models.CharField(
      verbose_name="Статус подобъекта",
      max_length=3,
      choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
      default='ST1')
   object = models.ForeignKey(Object)
```

Собственно задача: получить список объектов, у которых подобъктов с определённым статусом больше нуля.

Пока у меня только получилось отфильтровать по общему количеству подобъектов:

```
obj = Object.objects.annotate(subobj_count=Count('subobject').filter(...)
objs.filter(subobj_count__gt=0)
```

Я понимаю что можно написать функцию в модели и отслеживать её состояние в шаблоне, но в моём случае это не подходит.

Comment: Не понятно, что значит этот Ваш определенный статус больший нуля... У Вас статус принимает три значения ST1, ST2 и ST3..

Comment: К каждому объекту привязано несколько подобъектов. И у каждого подобъекта есть определённый статус.

Соответственно, мне нужны объекты,у кождого из которых количество привязанных подобъектов со статусом, например, ST2 больше нуля